# Can't access, delete, nor change the permissions of a cloned Github repo

Tags: windows, git, permissions, clone, git-clone

I was trying some things with Git (complete beginner) and cloned my "SmartPiCar" repository with git clone. As nothing appeared in the file explorer even showing hidden files, I checked with "ls" and found a directory which I'm not able to access nor delete: "d------ SmartPiCar"

I've tried to delete it with Windows commands and it says I lack permissions. But after changing them with "icacls 'SmartPiCar' /grant[:r] Users:F", it says "Succesfully processed 1 files" but permissions don't change.

Trying to delete it with "git rm" gives me this message: "fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories)"

More context: the cloning was successful & the repo is in a Drive folder with the files stored on Cloud only.

¿Does someone know what's the issue/how to solve it?

Comment: Your picture is missing. However, question: why are you operating on the Cloud? The point of github is that the history is backed up anyway, so you don't need any Cloud recovery functions. I am asking because I suspect whatever the cloud uses for synchronization is interfering.

Comment: Thanks, I've written more details and removed the pictures. I'm in the Cloud because I wanted to store training images in the same folder and access the from different computers, but if I can't solve the issue I'll do it out of the Cloud.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.